# How to make table with nested loop in JS

Tags: javascript, html

How to make the middle Column to be X rather than 0.

Here is my code:

```js
var table = document.createElement('table'), tr, td, row, cell;
for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
        td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.innerHTML = 0 
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: When you assign innerHTML to the td element, make sure that you are using 'X' instead of 0 if it is the center cell. So, you will want to do something like this: `td.innerHtml = (cell == 1 ? 'X' : 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use switch:

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        //console.log(cell);
        var cellText = "";
        // This switch picks content based on cell order
        switch(cell) {
        case 0: cellText = "0"; break;
        case 1: cellText = "X"; break;
        case 2: cellText = "0"; break;
        // Default value if cell count changes
        default: cellText = "Unknown cell!";
        }
        // Using `new Text` ensures the value is entered as text, not HTML
        // This can protect you from XSS or unexpected behavior
        td.appendChild(new Text(cellText));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

It's not the most maintainable solution, but good enough for simple script.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a check if the cell is 1. Then take an `'X'`.

```js
var table = document.createElement('table'),
    tr, td, row, cell;

for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (cell = 0; cell < 3; cell++) {
        td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.innerHTML = cell === 1 ? 'X' : 0;
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```